# Java/Spring Making Object available through interface?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

my use-case is as below, it's just a thought looking for possible implementation tricks. I know below description is kind of abusing the interface but looking for possible ways.

I have below class that has common data for application

```
class CommonData {
    //List<Data> commondata;
}
```

Now I've used them in most of `CalculationClasses` that uses CommonData like below:

```
GroupCalculation {
private CommonData data; // Spring injection
}
```

Now, this is fine to have CommonData in Calculation class. But there are lot of classes like filters, post-processors where CommonData doesn't really belong as member field. but these classes somehow need some commonData.

I am thinking if it possible to make it CommonData available through the interface like below but user class should need to provide implementation

```
interface CommonDataUser {
CommonData d = ??
public getCommonData() {
    return commonData
}
}
```

now whichever class wants commonData can only have to implement `CommonDataUser` but does not need to add the implementation.

for example:

```
class IDBasedFilter implements CommnDataUser {
// now I can use getCommonData() here to have access to commonData
}
```

is there a way to achieve this?

I want to use interface as way to quick use commonData just by marking a class with interface CommonDataUser, because if I had to add CommonData as field in every class, this will be a huge addition in every small class.

PS: if possible through annotation, that will also work
something like

```
@UsesCommonData(data="commonData")
class IDBasedFilter {
//will use commonData in some method
}
```

Comment: interfaces are not allowed to have members, what you want is a base class that has implementation for common data and extend it

Comment: Can we use default method in interface to supply the CommonData object in memory (CommonData bean is configured in spring xml)

Comment: It should be achievable with `@Configurable` and some **aspectj magic**

Comment: Any example or article please

Comment: See spring docs on [@Configurable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-atconfigurable)

Comment: Why not to declare `CommonData` instance as a bean. Then you can autowire it everywhere you need it. Just couple of strings of code. Or you mean accessing `CommonData` from non-component classes?

Comment: @KenBekov I want to avoid adding CommonData as member in small classes which are in good number and CommonData doesn't really belong to those classes. this is much like I want quick mark and use approach without addition in class